# Docker: Could not get container for XXX

Tags: docker

As you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/d178b675135a2b9d829e8b842c1a955b) I'm trying to start several docker container services in a CoreOS instance.

I've got a `journalctl -u authz.service` and it tells me that:

```
Error response from daemon: Could not get container for mongo.
```

It seems like `mongo` container is not reached.

Then, after having performed `systemctl start authz.service` it is started well. Each time I reboot the VM the problem appears again.

Any ideas?